# How do hexadecimal color values work in low-level computing?

Tags: colors

i assume it depends on computer display...
but does it depend on Operating System??

for example, color codes: `#ff0000,  #2e2e2e`  - three bytes used, obviously..
but how are these data (color codes) interpreted on the lowest level??
How does application renders color on the lowest level??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These codes are a compact representation of three integers between 0 and 255: Red, Blue, and Green.

They are rendered by the video card using the [RGB color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model).

Answer (score 1):

Computers use the RGB color model. In RGB, everything starts off as black and then you add some red/green/blue on top of that. The more of each color you add, the brighter it gets. Adding an equal amount of red/green/blue will create shades of grey (white if the max possible of all three colors are added).

This closely matches how the human eye picks up colors, so it works well (no light is black, max light we can see is blinding white, and light can be in different wavelengths to specify it's colour. If we see a red green and blue light right next to each other, it appears white to our eye. Look at your computer screen under a magnifying glass and you will be able to see it has red green and blue dots which all turn on when it's white).

The color codes you mentioned are "hex" color codes. It is three hex numbers joined together. #ff0000 is "ff red",  "00 green", "00 blue". ff is the highest possible two digit number in hex (it works out to 255 in standard decimal format), while 00 is the lowest possible two digit number (0 as a decimal number).

#2e2e2e is 2e of each red/green/blue, so creates a shade of grey. 2e is hex for the 47, which is much closer to 0 than to 255, so it creates a dark grey.

Hex is a "16 bit" number format, compared to the decimal format we are used which is 10 bit. This means you can have larger numbers with less digits, and 16 bit happens to be easier to work with for hardware video cards. The possible digits for the hex system are:

```
f, which is 15 in decimal
e, which is 14
d, which is 13
c, 12
b, 11
a, 10
9, which is 9 in decimal
8, which is 8
7, 7
6, 6
5, 5
4, 4
3, 3
2, 2
1, 1
0, 0
```

- More info about hex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal
- More info about RGB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model
- And more info about "web colors", which is what you're using: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Answer (score 1):

RGB is treated as red, green, blue, with each value being an integer from 0 to 255 inclusive. You could represent red for example as (255,0,0) or #FF0000, or many other different ways.

Whatever software is using the color tells your operating system's graphics drivers to output to your monitor. They vary from OS to OS, but the output that comes out of the port has to be standardized to the hardware.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model#RGB_devices

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can depend on the operating system. Older versions of Mac OS and Next used RGB values with a different gamma coefficient from that produced naturally by a monitor. Their video systems would convert these values before displaying them. Today you will mostly encounter sRGB, which was an attempt by Microsoft and HP to specify the average display system at the time it was created. Sometimes you'll run into other systems such as Adobe RGB, which has the ability to display slightly more colors than sRGB.